# работа со сквошем в гите

Tags: java, git, git-bash

Хочу сделать склеивание первого коммита и последнего, почитал, знаю что для этого делается сквош, но до этого проект пошёл по одному месту, я недолго думая просто клонировал его с гитхаба по новой, так вот когда смотрю reflog чтобы определить названия всех коммитов, та да м с, у меня только операции после клонирования. Вопрос, возможно ли склеить коммиты в склонированном проекте?

Comment: Git — это DVCS, смотрим, что означает D. А означает она **Distributed**. То есть реально репозиторий лежит во многих местах, в том числе и у вас на диске. То есть ответ — можно!

Comment: а какой операцией я могу посмотреть список всех своих коммитов?

Answer (score 1):

Да, все комиты смотрятся через `git log`, но конечно зависит от того как ты клонировал проект, если клонируя проект, ты просто перенес файлы в новый, то комиты не перелезут, хранятся они в .git папке. Вообще советую первый проект отшлифовать командой `git rebase -i --root`, а затем в первом репозитории разработки дать себе право на `git push -f` (force push это кажется) и исполнить саму команду. Вообще, горем научившись, советую push делать только решив саму задачу, перед этим прочитать коммиты, что собираешься пушить. А в самом репозитории сделать так, чтобы каждый пуш ждал очереди на одобрение.

Answer (score 0):

Команда git log выведет список всех коммитов